# Java Servlet not receiving values from JSP Form

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

This is my first time setting up a Java Servlet, I am trying to retrieve values into my Java Servlet from my input fields in my JSP Form when the user clicks a specific button.  I also, am unsure if I used the proper practice for creating my Servlet.  I simply right-clicked on my Apache Tomcat 8.0 server and then selected new Servlet.

Java Servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/loginServlet")
public class loginServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3719628899527775749L;

    public loginServlet() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

        // do some processing here...

        // get response writer
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

        // build HTML code
        String htmlRespone = "<html>";
        htmlRespone += "<h2>Your username is: " + username + "<br/>";      
        htmlRespone += "Your password is: " + password + "</h2>";    
        htmlRespone += "</html>";

        // return response
        writer.println(htmlRespone);
    }
}
```

JSP:

```
<form name="loginForm" action="loginServlet" method="post" id="loginForm">
            <div class="imgcontainer">
                <img src="images/img_avatar2.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
            </div>

            <div class="container">
                <label><b>Username</b></label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>

                <label><b>Password</b></label>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

                <button id="loginButton" name="loginButton" type="submit">Login</button>
                <button id="registerButton" name="registerButton" type="button">Register</button>
                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Remember me
            </div>

            <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
                <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
                <span class="psw">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your request attribute's name are `uname` and `psw` which are added on Jsp page. So you must change your doPost method like this.

```
String username = request.getParameter("uname");
String password = request.getParameter("psw");
```

Or

You must change your form in jsp page like this:

```
<label><b>Username</b></label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" required>
<label><b>Password</b></label>
<input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" required>
```